# Spring @Async performance

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I was searching about it for 4-5 days but I didn't find anything about it, I mean I tired it at Spring documentation or forums but nothing. Anyone can help me with some information or  description about the performance  of async (thread  usage etc.)

Comment: I admit to not knowing the answer, but I gotta say ... if I looked for just *1* day and couldn't find the answer, I think I'd whip up a simple application and found out for myself. That would have taken less time than you say you've spent searching... As it is this question is way too broad; there must be something specific you are looking for.

Comment: I doubt you will find any. What is it you seek? How it performs depends on how you configure it, your platform, your server, your thread pools,... It is only an abstract, the actual performance comes from the underlying thread pools and hardware.

Comment: well a very common  problem ,  users  send requests and I don't want to make them wait .. so  I want to make that the main thread can accept request  anytime when  there will be background threads which will do the heavy works.. and I tried it out, but I'm curious is it worth if for example  there are  2-3 sec  sql  queries ... I want opnions or some performance reports on some examples , so  I know  I wont find complete answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is slightly off-topic, since Spring async's support relies on a taskExecutor, and basically you can set it up choosing the implementation you want to. So there is no "performance comparison" to do.

In other words, it's not about @Async, thread management will depend on the specifics of the TaskExecutor and that is a Java thing that has nothing to do with Spring itself, apart from the fact that reducing boilerplate code to set it up.

Hope it helps you at least clarify how to research about this topic.